# bash or perl: toggle internal keyboard script

Tags: bash, perl, keyboard

Not very familiar with perl or bash scripting, trying to write a script to toggle internal keyboard (on laptop using external mechanical keyboard).

Toggle internal keyboard is easy enough to do with the xinput command:

```
$ xinput
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Identify id and float number of AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (built in keyboard).

```
$ xinput float 13
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
∼ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [floating slave]
```

To reattach keyboard use:

```
$ xinput reattach 13 3
```

No major issues here, just curious about writing a script to do this automatically, so far I have some mock up code which goes like this:

```
#bin/bash

val string = xinput | grep "AT keyboard"

if(parse(string).attached)
    val floatPartNumber = parse(string).id
    val reattachNumber = parse(string).slaveNumber

    # float keyboard
    xinput float floatPartNumber

    # create hidden file for storage
    file = makeFile(".reattachData")

    #add needed data to file
    writeTOFile(file)(floatPartNumber)
    writeTOFile(file)(reattachNumber)
fi
else
    val file = openFile(".reattachData") 
    val floatPartNumber = file.lineOne
    val reattachNumber = file.lineTwo

    # reattach keyboard
    xinput reattach floatPartNumber reattachNumber
end
```

I want to translate this into a bash or perl script, something easy to run without jumping through any hoops from my shell.

Either, what might be a good online resource, or resources, for me to reference while creating the proper syntax for this?
Or how would a functional version of this script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the output of xinput, but based on the assumption that it delivers lines like you provided, it would be something along these lines (no way to test it now):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $search = 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard';
my @xout = qx(xinput); # or use backticks instead of qx

my ($id,$slave) = map { # search for match and capture the numbers
    /$search.*id=(\d+)\s+\[(?:floating slave|slave  keyboard \((\d+)\))\]/
    ? ($1,$2) : ()
    } @xout;

if ( defined($slave) ) { # should be undef in case of 'floating slave'
    if (open(my $fh, '>', '.reattachData')) {
        $fh->print($id.$/.$slave);
        $fh->close;
    }
    qx(xinput float $id);
}
else {
    my @line = do { local(@ARGV) = '.reattachData';(<>) }; # read file
    chomp(@line);
    qx(xinput reattach $line[0] $line[1]);  
}
```

This of course assumes that your search term is always found. No error handling there...

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm, It's okay without error handling for my use, because it is a very predictable, particular situation when I would run this script with little uncertainty as to the hard coded string.